# How to borrow mutable value?

Tags: rust, redis

I've been trying to separate all my Redis operations in a separate implementation, but I got this error when I passed the Redis reference to the implementation.

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self.redis_client` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:30:21
   |
30 |         let _: () = self.redis_client.set("key", "value").unwrap();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Code:

```
use redis::{Commands};
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let redis_client_uri = String::from("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open(redis_client_uri)?;
    let mut redis = redis_client
        .get_connection()
        .expect("Failed to connect redis");

    let batch = vec!["Sample value".to_string()];
    CacheOperations::new(&redis, batch);
    Ok(())
}

struct CacheOperations<'a> {
    redis_client: &'a redis::Connection,
    batch: Vec<String>,
}

impl<'a> CacheOperations<'a> {
    fn new(redis_client: &'a redis::Connection, batch: Vec<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            redis_client: &redis_client,
            batch: batch,
        }
    }

    fn insert_batch(self) {
        let _: () = self.redis_client.set("key", "value").unwrap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `mut` keyword to indicate that a reference or value is mutable. When you use it with a lifetime, the `mut` goes after the lifetime usage (Ex: `&'abc mut x`).

```rust
use redis::{Commands};
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let redis_client_uri = String::from("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open(redis_client_uri)?;
    let mut redis = redis_client
        .get_connection()
        .expect("Failed to connect redis");

    let batch = vec!["Sample value".to_string()];
    // Use a mutable reference when creating the CacheOperations
    CacheOperations::new(&mut redis, batch);
    Ok(())
}

struct CacheOperations<'a> {
    // Store a mutable reference
    redis_client: &'a mut redis::Connection,
    batch: Vec<String>,
}

impl<'a> CacheOperations<'a> {
    // We need to consume a mutable reference
    fn new(redis_client: &'a mut redis::Connection, batch: Vec<String>) -> Self {
        // No need to reference the reference, we can store it as-is
        Self { redis_client, batch }
    }

    // While not required here, you can use mut self to state that self is mutable 
    // when a function consumes self as an owned value.
    fn insert_batch(mut self) {
        let _: () = self.redis_client.set("key", "value").unwrap();
    }
}
```